# App hangs by calling same Form 5 times. First 4 times work very nice, fifth time app hangs

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I just started developing a mobile app which has two forms, `FRM_Main` (Main Form) and `FRM_Party` (Party Form). We can open `FRM_Party` from `FRM_Main` by clicking on an Image. Code on Image is:

```pascal
procedure TFRM_Main.IMAGE_PartyClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FRM_Party := TFRM_Party.Create(Application);
  FRM_Party.Show;
end;
```

Now, when `FRM_Party` calls the `OnActivate` event, I am loading some data in a `TMSFMXTableView`. That code is:

```pascal
procedure TFRM_Party.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  TableView : TTMSFMXTableViewItem;
  I : Integer;
begin
  if Class_My_Pro_and_func.Func_DataBaseConnection then    //   Checks wethere database connection is active or not if not then it connect with database and returns bool value.
  Begin
    UniQuery.Close;
    UniQuery.SQL.Clear;
    UniQuery.SQL.Text := 'select * from db_stock.tbl_party where Reg_ID = :Reg_ID and Party_Delete <> :Party_Delete order by Party_Name ';
    UniQuery.ParamByName('Reg_ID').AsInteger := d_Glob_Reg_ID;
    UniQuery.ParamByName('Party_Delete').AsString := 'F';
    UniQuery.Open;

    TABLEVIEW_Party.BeginUpdate;

    if UniQuery.RecordCount > 0 then
    begin
      for I := 1 to UniQuery.RecordCount do
      begin
        TableView :=  TABLEVIEW_Party.Items.Add;
        TableView.Caption := UniQuery.Fields[1].AsString;
        TableView.Description := UniQuery.Fields[2].AsString + ' = ' + UniQuery.Fields[3].AsString;

        TABLEVIEW_Party.EndUpdate;

        UniQuery.Next;
      end;
    end
    else
      ShowMessage('No recored Found.');
  End
end;
```

On `FRM_Party` is a Back button which takes the user to `FRM_Main`. This button code is:

```pascal
procedure TFRM_Party.BTN_Party_BackClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
     UniQuery.Connection.Close; //   Closing Query connection
     DB_Connection.Disconnect;  //   Disconnecting database
     FreeAndNil(FRM_Party);
     Close;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Apart from the above code, nothing else is written on `FRM_Party`.

Now, the thing is that when I am running the application on mobile and opening/closing `FRM_Party` again and again, the first 4 times `FRM_Party` works very nice, but on the fifth time `FRM_Party` opens properly, but when closed the app hangs. I tried so many times by closing and opening the app. Every time the result is the same.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: First you should not call FreeAndNil before closing the form (thats calling a method on a destroyed object.

Comment: You should also get rid of those global form variables. You don't need them. You use them in methods of the form rather than Self, a known anti pattern. It's hard to see exactly what's going on here with the formatting of the Q being so broken. Please edit it to make the code readable. And please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `OnActivate` handler, your calls to `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` on `TABLEVIEW_Party` are unbalanced if `UniQuery.RecordCount` is not exactly 1. You are calling `BeginUpdate()` before entering the loop, which is fine, but then you are calling `EndUpdate()` inside the loop, thus calling it a different number of times than you call `BeginUpdate()`. You need to move those calls to the same level, eg:

```pascal
procedure TFRM_Party.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  TableView : TTMSFMXTableViewItem;
  I : Integer;
begin
  if not Class_My_Pro_and_func.Func_DataBaseConnection then
    Exit;

  UniQuery.Close;
  UniQuery.SQL.Text := 'select * from db_stock.tbl_party where Reg_ID = :Reg_ID and Party_Delete <> :Party_Delete order by Party_Name ';
  UniQuery.ParamByName('Reg_ID').AsInteger := d_Glob_Reg_ID;
  UniQuery.ParamByName('Party_Delete').AsString := 'F';
  UniQuery.Open;

  if UniQuery.RecordCount > 0 then
  begin
    TABLEVIEW_Party.BeginUpdate;
    try
      for I := 1 to UniQuery.RecordCount do
      begin
        TableView := TABLEVIEW_Party.Items.Add;
        TableView.Caption := UniQuery.Fields[1].AsString;
        TableView.Description := UniQuery.Fields[2].AsString + ' = ' + UniQuery.Fields[3].AsString;
        UniQuery.Next;
      end;
    finally
      TABLEVIEW_Party.EndUpdate;
    end;
  end
  else
    ShowMessage('No record Found.');
end;
```

Also, in your back button's `OnClick` handler, you are calling `Close()` on `FRM_Party` after calling `FreeAndNil(FRM_Party)`.

On mobile platforms prior to RAD Studio 10.4, [object lifetime is managed by ARC](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers). Calling `FreeAndNil(FRM_Party)` will not actually free the `FRM_Party` object, it will simply set the `FRM_Party` variable to `nil`. The object is not freed because `Application` still has an active reference to it.

But in RAD Studio 10.4 onwards, [ARC is no longer used](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/What%27s_New), so calling `FreeAndNil(FRM_Party)` will actually destroy the object. So calling `Close()` after afterwards will crash your code.

The correct way to free a `TForm` when it is closed is to use its `OnClose` event instead, eg:

```pascal
procedure TFRM_Party.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  If FRM_Party = Self then
    FRM_Party := nil;
end;

procedure TFRM_Party.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
end;

procedure TFRM_Party.BTN_Party_BackClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UniQuery.Connection.Close;
  DB_Connection.Disconnect;
  Close;
end;
```

Comment: In firemonkey i tried with db_connection.disconnect to disconnect database which hangs  my application.  now i tried with db_connection.connected := False; which works greatly without any hang or other probs.